# authorization header is missing - ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, authentication, ionic2

I am quite new in Ionic framework.
I am getting this error when I want register a user in service - auth in Ionic https://apps.ionic.io/app/

```
error   
link    
message "Authorization header is missing."
type    "Unauthorized"
meta    
request_id  "243a7cd6-d598-4919-c9e9-ac6d4cf20c4b"
version "2.0.0-beta.0"
status  401
```

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';


import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { ChatPage } from '../pages/chat/chat';
import { About } from '../pages/about/about';


const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': '5818f930'
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    ChatPage,
    About

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    ChatPage,
    About

  ],
  providers: [
    SplashScreen,
    StatusBar,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And here login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Auth, User, UserDetails, IDetailedError } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  showLogin:boolean = true;
  email:string = '';
  password:string = '';
  name:string = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public auth: Auth, public user: User, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public loadingCtrl:LoadingController) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello LoginPage Page');
  }

  /*
  for both of these, if the right form is showing, process the form,
  otherwise show it
  */
  doLogin() {
    if(this.showLogin) {
      console.log('process login');

      if(this.email === '' || this.password === '') {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title:'Register Error',
          subTitle:'All fields are required',
          buttons:['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
        return;
      }

      let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Logging in..."
      });
      loader.present();

      this.auth.login('basic', {'email':this.email, 'password':this.password}).then(() => {
        console.log('ok i guess?');
        loader.dismissAll();
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
      }, (err) => {
        loader.dismissAll();
        console.log(err.message);

        let errors = '';
        if(err.message === 'UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY') errors += 'Email isn\'t valid.<br/>';
        if(err.message === 'UNAUTHORIZED') errors += 'Password is required.<br/>';

        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title:'Login Error',
          subTitle:errors,
          buttons:['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
      });
    } else {
      this.showLogin = true;
    }
  }

  doRegister() {
    if(!this.showLogin) {
      console.log('process register');

      /*
      do our own initial validation
      */
      if(this.name === '' || this.email === '' || this.password === '') {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title:'Register Error',
          subTitle:'All fields are required',
          buttons:['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
        return;
      }

      let details: UserDetails = {'email':this.email, 'password':this.password, 'name':this.name};
      console.log(details);

      let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Registering your account..."
      });
      loader.present();

      this.auth.signup(details).then(() => {
        console.log('ok SignUp');
        this.auth.login('basic', {'email':details.email, 'password':details.password}).then(() => {
          loader.dismissAll();
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        });

      }, (err:IDetailedError<string[]>) => {
        loader.dismissAll();
        let errors = '';
        for(let e of err.details) {
          console.log(e);
          if(e === 'required_email') errors += 'Email is required.<br/>';
          if(e === 'required_password') errors += 'Password is required.<br/>';
          if(e === 'conflict_email') errors += 'A user with this email already exists.<br/>';
          //don't need to worry about conflict_username
          if(e === 'invalid_email') errors += 'Your email address isn\'t valid.';
        }
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title:'Register Error',
          subTitle:errors,
          buttons:['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
      });

    } else {
      this.showLogin = false;
    }
  }
```

I have no idea where is the problem.
This is package.json

```
{
 "name": "ionic-hello-world",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
        "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
        "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
        "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
        "@ionic-native/core": "3.6.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.6.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.6.1",
        "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "angular2-moment": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
        "firebase": "^4.0.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.1.1",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "rxjs": "5.1.1",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.0.1",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.10"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
        "typescript": "~2.2.1"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [],
    "description": "KarolinaApp: An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send username password using authorization header.

please try as following

use the URL as `http://username:password@example.com/`. In this case automatically generates authorization header using your username and password.